# Dotnet Core MVC - Apply action filter to specific controllers only

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have worked in MVC on .Net 4 and I had my action filters overridden in the controller class. That way I can have multiple controllers, each with a unique `OnActionExecuting` method.

Now I'm working on Dotnet Core 2.1 and things are a little different so I can't get the same methodology to work.
I have a controller for an API that inherits `ControllerBase` and then another controller for serving pages, that one inherits `Controller`.
I created my action filter class that derives from `ActionFilterAttribute`.

I then registered my action filter by using this line:

```
services.AddMvc(config => { config.Filters.Add(typeof(MyActionFilter)); })
```

The problem is that the filter now applies to the API controller as well as the pages controller. Is there a way the action filter can be applied to specific controllers only?

I used [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1) as a reference for my initial action filter implementation.

I know that inside the `OnActionExecuting` method I can use `context.Controller.GetType()` to compare it to the types of my individual controllers, but I would prefer to avoid that, and instead specify which controllers should use which action filters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use attribute to mark the controllers you want to apply filters. Its described on the documentation page you provided in your question

Comment: @maxs87 I tried that, eg. `[ServiceFilter(typeof(MyActionFilter))]` but it complained about the filter not being registered - I skipped this as well: `config.Filters.Add(typeof(MyActionFilter))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
services.AddMvc(config => { config.Filters.Add(typeof(MyActionFilter)); })
```

The above source code is used when you want to apply the global filter that mean every API will have the affected.

So to specific particular Controller you just simply add [MyActionFilter] atribute to you controller

Example:

```
[MyActionFilter]
public class HomeController : Controller {
   public ViewResult Index(){..}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this one solved my problem.

It turns out, you can also use this `[ServiceFilter(typeof(MyActionFilter))]`
I'm not sure what the difference is, but I'll stick to what is known and use your recommendation.

Comment: see here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#dependency-injection - ServiceFilterAttribute

Answer (score 5):

1. First of All Register Your filter in your startup.cs

   ```
   services.AddScoped<"---FilterNameHere----">();
   ```
2. Put Your Filter in controller like

   ```
   [ServiceFilter(typeof("----FilterNameHere---"))]
    public class HomeController : ControllerBase

   {
       public IActionResult Index()
        {//do your code here}
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for an answer too. Both above confused me. Went to the page of the documentation...

Two ways of doing this in a clean way.

1. An action filter for all actions of all controllers.

   ```
   public class YourActionFilter : IActionFilter
   {
       public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
       {
           throw new System.NotImplementedException();
       }

       public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
       {
           throw new System.NotImplementedException();
       }
   }

   And in startup do

   services.AddControllers(c => { c.Filters.Add(new YourActionFilter()); })
   ```
2. An Attribute that you want to use only on specific actions which implements TypeFilterAttribute and has an private class that implemements an action filter.

   ```
   public class YourActionFilterAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
   {
      public YourActionFilterAttribute() : base(typeof(TheActionFilter)) { }

      private class TheActionFilter : IActionFilter
      {
           public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
           {
               throw new System.NotImplementedException();
           }

           public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
           {
               throw new System.NotImplementedException();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Now you only need to add it to a whole controller or to a specific action

```
   [YourActionFilter]
   public class HomeController : ControllerBase
   {
       [YourActionFilter]
       public IActionResult Index()
       {//do your code here}
   }
```